# Point Derivation other than Directional Derivatives

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In his book *An Introduction to Manifolds* (2nd edition) on page no. 13, Loring Tu defines a derivation at point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a linear operator $D:C_p^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule: 
$$D(fg) = f D(g) + D(f) g.$$

Here $C_p^{\infty}$ is the equivalence class of $(f, U)$, where $f$ is $C^{\infty}(U)$ and $U$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ in the topological space $\mathbb{R}^n$. A function $(g, V)$ is equivalent to $(f,U)$ iff $\exists$ a neighbourhood of $p$ given by $W \subset U \cap V$ such that $f(x) = g(x) \, \forall x \in W$, where $g$ is $C^{\infty}(V)$ and $V$ is a neighbourhood of $p$.

Tu writes in the proof of Lemma 2.1 on the same page:

> As we do not know if every derivation at $p$ is a directional derivative, we need to prove this lemma using only the defining properties of a derivation at $p$.

**Question**

Does there exist any derivation at $p$ which is not a directional derivative? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu answers your question in Theorem 2.2. For each direction $v$ we have the directional derivative $\phi(v)$ which is a derivation at $p$, and Theorem 2.2 says that $\phi$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no! Check that every directional derivative (a vector space of dimension n) is a derivation and than observe the dimension of the space of derivations (use the differencial of a chart).